# Button won't execute Javascript no matter what I do

Tags: javascript, html, css

The following code below is supposed to work as follows, the user is suppose to input a URL, Proxy IP & Proxy port once they click "test" it would grab the response code and replace the html h5 "awaiting test" with the new status code text. I made another version of this same exact script and it worked via client but when you run via electron app and click test button all you get is an error how do I get the button "test" to execute the script? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Index HTML**

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Simple Tester</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.3/semantic.min.css"/>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.3/semantic.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      </head>
    <body>
    <h1 id="header">Simple Tester v1.00</h1>

    <div class="content">
    <div class="proxytesturls">
    <h3 id="url" style="color:#4a04de;" >Site URL:</h3>
    <div class="ui large input">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Google.com" id="siteurltext">
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="proxyip">
    <h3 id="ip" style="color:#4a04de;">Proxy IP:</h3>
    <div class="ui large input" id="proxyinput">
    <input type="text" placeholder="1.1.1.1" id="proxyipinput">
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="proxyport">
    <h3 id="port" style="color:#4a04de;">Proxy Port:</h3>
    <div class="ui large input">
    <input type="text" placeholder="8080" id="proxyportinput">
    </div>
    </div>

    <input type="button" id="btnclick" value="test" onclick="pingProxy();">

    <div class="ui raised segment" id="logger">
    <h2 style="color:#4a04de;" id="logstext">Logger</h2>
    <h5 id="awaitingtest">Awaiting test...</h5>
    </div>
    </div>

    <script src="tester.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

**tester.js**

```js
  const request = require('request');
  var pingProxy = require('ping-proxy');

  var url = document.getElementById("siteurltext").value;
  var proxyip = document.getElementById("proxyipinput").value;
  var proxyport = document.getElementById("proxyportinput").value;



  pingProxy({
    proxyHost: proxyip,
    proxyPort: proxyport,
    proxyTestUrl: 'https://', url

  },

   function (err, options, statuscode) {

  if (statuscode == 407) {
    document.getElementById('awaitingtest').innerHTML = ('Status: Proxy Authentication Required');
  }

  if (statuscode == 200) {
    document.getElementById('awaitingtest').innerHTML = ('Status: Valid Proxy!');
  }

  if (statuscode == 403) {
    document.getElementById('awaitingtest').innerHTML = ('Status: Banned Proxy!');
  }

  if (statuscode == 401) {
    document.getElementById('awaitingtest').innerHTML = ('Status: Unauthorized!');
  }

  }
);
```

**Main.js**

```js
const electron = require('electron')

  const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')

    function createWindow () {
      // Create the browser window.
      win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})

      // and load the index.html of the app.
      win.loadFile('index.html')
    }

    app.on('ready', createWindow)
```

Errors:

Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function
    at pingProxyAsync (C:\Users***********\proxytester\node_modules\ping-proxy\ping-proxy.js:21)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (index.html:37)

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: at HTMLInputElement.onclick (index.html:37)` is not the complete error; please copy and paste the **complete** error into the question. Separately: There's a **lot** of code here. You're better off reducing it to a [mcve] (note the "minimal"); it makes it more likely people will try to answer.

Comment: I haven't used Electron, so I could be mistaken, but I'd have to guess that since `pingProxy` is in imported into a module, it isn't a global. (That's true generally in Node.js and RequireJS/CommonJS environments.) HTML `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers can only call global functions. Instead, use modern event handling (`addEventListener`) to set up your click handler.

Comment: Did you try moving the script download of tester.js immediately after the body?

Comment: Moving the script as stated still dosn't do anything.

I'm trying to figure out what my mistake is my tester.js code looks good I don't see any errors the issue is getting the button to execute tester.js and output the result to the h5 "Awaiting test..."

Answer (score 0):

You may need to concatenate the proxyTestUrl. Replace the comma with a plus sign.

```
pingProxy({
proxyHost: proxyip,
proxyPort: proxyport,
proxyTestUrl: 'https://' + url
```

},